# Symfony : detect link inside textarea

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to detect links inside a textarea and display it in my view.

So I tried these preg_replace instructions

```
 preg_replace("/([\w]+:\/\/[\w-?&;#~=\.\/\@]+[\w\/])/i","<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"$1\">$1</A>",$detail);


preg_replace('@(http)?(s)?(://)?(([a-zA-Z])([-\w]+\.)+([^\s\.]+[^\s]*)+[^,.\s])@', '<a target="ref" href="http$2://$4">$1$2$3$4</a>', $detail);
```

and it's done great on the whole except when I got URL containing special character like follow :

```
http://website.info/x-y-z-a/~~~~dcvvvc|cvvcvc~~~/cvcvcv-5-1.html.
```

Then it's not working at all.

Thanks

Comment: Does the dot at the end part of the string `cvcvcv-5-1.html.`?

Comment: No it's just the end of sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I turned out that I forgot to add '|'

```
$test = preg_replace("/([\w]+:\/\/[\w-?&;#~|=\.\/\@]+[\w\/])/i", "<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"$1\">$1</A>", $detail);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could encode your URL before running the regex in order to turn all special characters into the % equivalent.

See http://php.net/manual/fr/function.urlencode.php